# Shortcut to open terminal in `pwd` if active window is another terminal or Nautilus

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I have made a custom keybinding in Gnome such that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> opens a gnome terminal. Now I would like to improve it such that if the window active when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is Nautilus or another Gnome terminal, the opened terminal's working directory is the same as the previously active window. Allow me to present a few of the ideas which have failed:

1. At least in Gnome terminal you get the desired behaviour from `File -> Open Terminal` (how about Nautilus?). You can add a shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to this action, however, it is overridden by the system-wide <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> which opens a terminal at `$HOME`.
2. I have seen some people in here alias the `cd` command such that it always stores the entered directory in a file. I do not think this is a good solution: You can use `cd` in one terminal, then switch to another and hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. You will not get the desired behaviour. I also don't like tinkering with `cd` in this way.
3. I tried looking for ways to query Gnome for it's active window from bash (or Python), and possibly it's working directory. In X there's tools such as `xdotool` but I use Wayland. It seems that Wayland prevents such actions out of security.

Any suggestions much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I should have posted this in Unix&Linux SE?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the existing `<Ctrl><Shift>t` instead?

Comment: I could, or I could assign a shortcut of my choice which is different than `<Super>t`. But I would like it to be the same as the system-wide one which _is_ (in my case) `<Super>t`. I just want to press `<Super>t` whenever I need a terminal (whether I'm already in a terminal or not), and I want it to be in the right directory from the start, whenever possible.